# How to get cookies saved by a Chrome Custom Tabs?

Tags: android, cookies, webchromeclient

I'm looking for a way to retrieve a cookie saved by a [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs). I tried to use the `CookieManager` but the result is always null.

Here's my code :

```
CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url); // return null
```

`url` value is correctly url encoded and exactly the same url which launch my Chrome Custom Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the CookieManager only works for a WebView and not the Custom Tabs.